# Pyqt4 on Ubuntu 20.04 install

Tags: pyqt

I use a chess application called "Lucaschess" and it needs PyQt4 module to work. Is it possible to install Pyqt4 on Ubuntu 20.04? I understand that Ubuntu no longer supports this package but is there anyway which I can work around?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Qt4 packages can still be obtained from [third party PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you have to download `python-qt4` binding from previous Ubuntu 18.04 LTS release manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qt-assistant-compat/libqtassistantclient4_4.6.3-7build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libqtassistantclient4_4.6.3-7build1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-qt4/python-qt4_4.12.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-qt4_4.12.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-pyaudio/python-pyaudio_0.2.11-1build2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-pyaudio_0.2.11-1build2_amd64.deb
```

As the result the Python2-Qt4 binding will be installed. Then you know what to do.

Also note that there is fresh version of [lucaschess](https://lucaschess.blogspot.com/2020/06/version-r.html) [here](https://github.com/lukasmonk/lucaschessR) with Qt5 as dependency.

Comment: I have added installation of python-pyaudio. How did you installed LucasChess? There is a [PKGBUID for ArchLinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=lucaschess-git), but looks very complicated. This is why I am asking.

Comment: Yeah i installed by the following the instructions here: https://github.com/lukasmonk/lucaschess/blob/master/Linux/LinuxInstallation.md and got the pyaudio error.

Comment: By the way, lucaschess is working now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libqtassistantclient4: Requires: libqt4-network (> = 4: 4.8.1) but cannot be installed